# Why my document cookie object is not storing any cookie in chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, ubuntu-16.04

**OS - Ubuntu 16.04/vscode/chrome**

**My alert box does not contain the passed cookie**

**Chrome Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) unknown (64-bit)**

```js
document.cookie = "username=geeky";
alert(document.cookie);
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine when I test it.

Comment: All cookies are enabled. My console also rendering nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have cookies disabled or you opened this website from html file.

Comment: All cookies are enabled. My console also rendering nothing.

Comment: I tried this http://127.0.0.1:5500/cookie.html. Its working